# Link to route without additional JS code

Tags: sapui5

I'm a beginner to OpenUI5 and have written a menu like below:

**view:**

```
<NavigationList id="navigationList" width="12rem">
  <NavigationListItem text="People" icon="sap-icon://card" select="goToRoute"></NavigationListItem>
</NavigationList>
```

**controller:**

```
goToRoute: function() {
    this.getRouter().navTo("peoplelist");
}
```

That works, but it's bad, as I have a couple of menu items and JS events for each of them.

I wish I had something like this below, without any JS behind, but couldn't find anything in documentation and examples.

**view:**

```
<NavigationList id="navigationList" width="12rem">
  <NavigationListItem text="People" icon="sap-icon://card" linkToRoute="peoplelist"></NavigationListItem>
</NavigationList>
```

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a generic event handler which derives the target route from the corresponding item. To achieve this you can make use of custom data which you can add to controls in a declarative way. For this add the following line to your opening View tag:

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
```

Adopt your navigation list:

```
<NavigationList id="navigationList" width="12rem">
      <NavigationListItem text="People" icon="sap-icon://card" select="onItemSelect" custom:route="peopleList"/>
</NavigationList>
```

And your controller:

```
onItemSelect : function(event) {
   var item = event.getSource();
   var route = item.data("route");
   this.getRouter().navTo(route);
}
```

[Here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/91f0c3ee6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) you find further details.